# how to update column in data frame based on condition

Tags: python, dataframe

How to update column IsLCap column in dataframe based on Lvalue column whether it is capitilized or not.

df.loc[df.Lvalue.istitle(), 'IsLCap'] = 1  # need to be corrected

getting an error -AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'istitle'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You access string functions with `.str`. This should work:

`df.loc[df.Lvalue.str.istitle(), 'IsLCap'] = 1`

**Update**
To check the length of the strings in the column you can use the string method `.str.len`:

`df.loc[df.Lvalue.str.len() < 3, 'less_than_three'] = 1`

[Pandas Series string methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html)

Comment: i need to check string length also, df.loc[len(df.Lvalue)<3, 'LlessThan3'] = 1 ## need to correct this. How can i do this

Comment: I have updated my answer with a solution. If this works for you, you should accept/upvote the answer. @SUHASINIKL